# Configuring JBoss JNDI to bind to JNDI on different server?

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, jndi

I have two JBoss servers, JbossA and JbossB. Each has its own JNDI. Now I have a JMS on JbossA with the name jms/Client and a JMS on JbossB with the name jms/Server.

Now I want an application on JbossA to be able to access jms/Server using its own JNDI. Also I'd like an application on JbossB to acces jms/Client using the jndi-name jms/Client1 using its own JNDI.

In Short:

```
JbossA/
       JNDI/
            jms/Client
            jms/Server  -> JbossB/JNDI/jms/Server


JbossB/
       JNDI/
            jms/Server
            jms/Client1  -> JBossA/JNDI/jms/Client
```

- AppA on JbossA accesses jms/Client and jms/Server using JbossA/JNDI
- AppB on JbossB accesses jms/Server and jms/Client1 using JbossB/JNDI

Two questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. If so, how would I go about configuring this in JBoss EAP 6.0.1 (Jboss 7.1) ?

Comment: This is purely an application / jndi question. I'm removing the hornetq tag

Comment: You're right. apologies...

Answer (score 0):

First, I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to look up an MDB, those are supposed to be invoked by the container only (by the JMS implementation to be precise), but if you're trying to look up a JMS publisher or connection then what your asking for totally makes sense.

With that said, JBoss 7 introduced a nice new feature, the [Remote Naming Project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) does exactly what you need, the problem is that, apparently, it is only able to bind remote EJBs, you could give it a try though. It is my personal opinion that the JBoss team (to whom I'm infinitely thankful for such a great work) is a little left behind in this (maybe they have a good reason for it?), other JEE containers have been able to do this for quite a while, in Weblogic it's called [Foreign JNDI Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jndi/ManageForeignJNDI.html), but anyway, if the above didn't work and you absolutely need to do this, I'm afraid the only solution left is to do it programmatically, in that case keep reading below.

The `javax.naming` API provides a way to bind **references** to objects outside your local naming context, simply use [InitialContext.bind(String name, Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#bind%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), but instead of binding the actual object bind an instance of [javax.naming.Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Reference.html). As you can see from the javadocs, to create the Reference instance you need to provide an instance of an implementation of [javax.naming.RefAddr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/RefAddr.html) containing the necessary info to locate the remote object and an implementation of [javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory.html) which is the object that under the hood will do the actual look up to get your remote object. It'd look something like this:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ForeignJNDIObjectRefAddr refAddr = getRemoteObjectJNDIInfo(...;
ctx.bind("jms/Server", new Reference("java.lang.Object",
                refAddr, ForeignJNDIObjectFactory.class.getName(), null));
```

in this case you would have implemented `ForeignJNDIObjectRefAddr` and `ForeignJNDIObjectFactory`, when it's time to do the look up, your  `ForeignJNDIObjectFactory.getObjectInstance` method will get invoked with the `ForeignJNDIObjectRefAddr` instance as its first parameter, so that you have all the necessary info to do the look up and return your remote object. good luck!

Comment: I didn't mention anything about an MDB? I want to look up a JMS connection. I'm aware about the Remote Naming Project for EJBs, but unfortunately, that has no use for my JMSs. Also, I do not wish to bind the remote JMS using java, since I want it (for the application) to be completely transparent where the JMS comes from. The application contacts a single JNDI, which provides what he asks for... that's the idea anyway.

Comment: yeahp, you want to look up a connection, that's what i thought. On the other hand, like i said, if you don't want to pay for a license, for what i know it looks like you don't have many other choices. Regarding the programmatic approach, that's exactly the way to make that your business doesn't have to know where the JMS comes from, it could all be centralized, loaded from config and would only have to do it once, the way you implement it is totally up to you, I only described the basic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. It is easier if you can upgrade your EAP version though. If you have EAP subscription, I don't see a reason for keeping that old version in place. There are lot of bugs fixed since.

From [EAP 6.2.0 release notes](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html-single/6.2.0_Release_Notes/index.html):

> External JNDI Federation
>
> A Naming subsystem configuration has been added to the JBoss EAP 6 configuration
>   that enables an administrator to connect an external
>   naming system to the JBoss EAP 6 JNDI. This capability replaces the
>   ExternalContextMBean from JBoss EAP 5.

However, even with EAP 6.0.x you could use

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.2">
    <bindings>
        <object-factory name="java:global/myExtContext" module="my.custom.module" class="my.example.class.ExternalContextObjectFactory"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

And implement ExternalContextObjectFactory in my.custom.module module like

```
public class ExternalContextObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory {
    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(final Object obj, final Name name, final Context nameCtx, final Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws Exception {
      Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
      if(environment != null)
        env.putAll(environment);
      env.set( /* all the properties you will need for your target context */ );
      return new InitialContext(environment);
    }
}
```

So your target context would be bound to `java:global/myExtContext`.

Answer (score 0):

This is feasible using External JNDI Federation included in EAP 6.x. You need to define a global bound properties. Rest is for you to explore :)

Shishir